# jQuery and dynamic Tabs and data

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to build Chrome Extension to my team.

we have salesforce website for ticket system.
in the system we have list of tickets and tabs to open and see the data of the ticket.
i would like to add text and imgaes as html,css,js code to the Data inside the tab.
and when i click on a tab it will change or add the html code i want.

my code so far:

**Manifest:**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Help Desk SalesForce Helper",  
"description": "Help Desk SalesForce Helper",  
"version": "1.0", 

"options_page" : "options.html",

"permissions": [    
"<all_urls>",
"tabs",
"storage"
] ,



"browser_action": { 
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icons/19.png",
        "38": "images/icons/38.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
},

"icons": {
    "16": "images/icons/16.png",
    "19": "images/icons/19.png",
    "38": "images/icons/38.png",
    "64": "images/icons/64.png",
    "128": "images/icons/128.png"
},
"background":{
 "scripts":["eventPage.js"],
 "persistent":false
},

"content_scripts":[  
         {
             "matches":["https://icl--bmcservicedesk.eu32.visual.force.com/*"],
             "js":["jquery-3.4.1.min.js","content.js"]

      }

]
```

}

**content.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.x-tab-inner').on('click',function(){
    alert('The New or old Tab is Clicked');
});
```

});

as you can see i have the incidents tab with lists of tickets, when i click on ticket the tab is open.

[image]

tab data that i want to change or add for each ticket open.
each ticket have is own data .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which kind of information do you want to add if you mean html elements why not create the elements you want to add in content.js and then append each element where you want it to fit could you supply more informatio or an example of html/css/js you would want to add

Comment: i want to add P elements, links, images.
my problem is the tabs.
after i open a new tab in the website. the extension won't recognize it. and when i use the console to insert elements it adds them to all of the tabs and now working only on the tav i view right now. any suggestion?

Comment: maybe test how the site knows which tab is clicked and then have like a class for each tab and hide all the classes except classes that are the same as the tab